# How to export bookmarks from Chrome in Android?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, chrome-for-android

I need to import bookmarks from my Chrome Android mobile. Is there any direct way to do it? Please do not suggest to sync Chrome account in desktop and do import from there, my Sync rights has been disabled by admin in Chrome desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays (2023), for this question, one can try my Xposed module [ChromeXt](https://github.com/JingMatrix/ChromeXt), which is an active open source project.
From its README:
Bookmarks can be exported in HTML format through the `Developer options` menu.

There is also a [dicussion](https://github.com/JingMatrix/ChromeXt/discussions/62) about this function, which might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Google offers [downloading your data](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3024190?hl=en) from the Google products you use. If Chrome's data was synced on Android side, you could download from [here](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout/custom/chrome?pli=1).

Comment: This gave me an archive with a bunch of files, all of them containing between one and 600 repetitions of the string `"Encrypted": "Your data is encrypted and cannot be exported."`.

Comment: @DanielSaner This is strange and do not reflect my previous experience with this.
Maybe the archive (a zip archive I suppose) is now encrypted globally with some password you only can have? Maybe are you enrolled in their Advanced Protection Program that requires physical token?
Beside of this, apart from any security settings changed on Google or, things they may have changed lately, or a bug in the late time, I dunno, you could try to reach them asking directly to Google support.

Comment: Worked. Imported bookmarks into duckduckgo

Comment: OP specifically said NO sync stuff.

Comment: @Frotz anyway, yes it requires to have Chrome Android synced with Google, but does not require to have the Desktop synced with Google also, that was the OP problem.
Sadly there's no way AFAIK to handle and save the data only locally, both on Android or Pc. I have also tried some applications in the past, promising to do this, but they were outdated and not working at all.

Comment: can't comment "Google Bookmark Import tool" response (no reputation) @Igor_K
I want to point out Store App description info:
1) "will download bookmarks from https://www.google.com/bookmarks (...) add them on (...) browser." - App will try to do REVERSE transfer respect OP request, and, will read from Chrome Synced data online. Google address obsolete also.
2) "Chrome ... will not import/export folder structure"
App will garble bookmarks by removing folder structure
3) App latest update 19 nov 2015: totally obsolete , and totally unsupported on creator's site http://www.it-dan.com/

Comment: @Frotz OP said exactly that:
<<Please do not suggest to sync Chrome account IN DESKTOP and do import from there, my Sync rights has been disabled by admin in Chrome DESKTOP.>>
It is really different form what you say. It says to not suggest to use sync IN DESKTOP, not in Android. Please don't complain about a thing without taking time to understanding it well.

Comment: @Frotz My solutions is:
1) currently only viable solution, because all previous extension made to work with Chrome bookmark are obsolete and made not working by the subsequent Chromium code modifications
2) not requires using Sync ON DESKTOP, as required by Original Poster
3) let you free to transition to any browser and bring your bookmarks (simply let the new browser read the Google Export uncompressed file).
4) yes, it requires to have a Google account to be able to sync the data ON ANDROID (as NOT expressly excluded by original poster, this should then be deemed as PERMITTED by him).

Comment: **Moderator's warning:** [don't use comment thread for debate](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). Once is enough to state your opinion, no need to push it. Just vote (or don't) and move on.

Comment: (can't comment other response for: reputation) The new 2023 solution by @jingmatrix seems to be able to let users to export bookmarks from Chrome on Android directly, only it seems little difficult to implement on a standard user's phone. If someone could test it, we should check if it is able to export the full tree structure of the bookmarks, or only the links as other old Chrome extensions were doing. At the moment I can't test it (no phone)

Answer (score -1):

[Google Bookmark Import Tool](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.itdan.bookmarktool) helps in cases when you need to backup Chrome Android bookmarks.

It is simple to use and generated file can be transferred from phone/tablet easily.